# Formatting so that all the second strings align regardless of the first strings length

Tags: python, formatting

Something that always trips me up is formatting. I can't really give you the test cases but I'll provide I  photo of what I get vs what I want. But it should be simple to solve.

[image: What I get]
[image: What I want]

I just need help with aligning all the prices regardless of the length of the title.

Here is the code for what I have.

```
for book in titles:
    self.info_text.insert(END, f"{book[0]:<150} {book[1]:<10}")
    self.info_text.insert(END, "\n")
```

Comment: The issue is not your python code. It's the font, as the font isn't a monospace : a font where every char takes the same width. Here an 'i' take less width as an "m" or a "w". **You can't align text without a monospace font**.

Comment: That makes sense and is a little annoying. Thanks!

Comment: Well you can, but not by inserting a certain number of spaces.

Comment: I just thought it was the code that was wrong, not the font but I changed it to a monospace font and it works.